# QGIS: How to properly project CRS EPSG:3035-ETRS89-extended/LAEA Europe to EPSG:25832/ UTM zone 32N

Tags: qgis

I have multiple shapefiles with the above CRS and with all I have a problem to reproject them to a smaller scale CRS as EPSG:25832 as with the normal procedure: **right-click,export, save features as, and then setting the wanted CRS** (in my case it is EPSG:25832/ UTM zone 32N). In my case, it seems to set the correct CRS, but somehow defines very weird extents, for example, for one it created the extent in Turkey.

In QGIS the CRSs are described as follows :

[image]

[image]

Does someone know what could cause the problem with the extent? I see that they use different methods. Does this maybe have to do with it?

This is how it looks in my original data:
[image]

and this, when I have projected it to EPSG 25832
[image]
However, when I add them to my project, which is set to EPSG:25832, they align correctly. Therefore, to me it seems, the original data seem to be fine. So I thought it may not be the data to be corrupt, but that I don't use the correct reprojection-technique? Therefore I posted images of the two definitions of the two CRSs.

Comment: those are the extents of the CRS not your data, please show us what your data looks like

Comment: @IanTurton I added a picture of my original shapefile, which is a line feature shapefile. It is just one of two files with the CRS EPSG 3035, and with both I have a problem to set the CRS properly.

Comment: I'm not completely sure, if I have the solution to this, but it may not work, because, the CRS I wanted to use for my data does not completely cover it's extent. My data is over whole Germany, but as you can see above, the extent of the CRS EPSG:25832 does not cover whole Germany. That may explain the weird results with the extents.

Comment: that would certainly be a problem